# Problemas al ejecutar procedimientos en un mismo fichero sql en oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy ejecutando con Maven un script que contiene varias sentencias de este tipo pero la consola de windows me muestra el error. (Sustituí el con tenido de «to_blob()» por xxxxxxx por no subir datos reales al foro):

```
    --informe 101
DECLARE
    myBlobVar BLOB := to_blob('xxxxxxx');
    dest_lob BLOB;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO SCR_REPORTS (ID, REPORT, TYPE_REPORT, TYPE_ARCH, ALL_ARCH, ALL_OFICS, ALL_PERFS, DESCRIPTION, "DATA")
        VALUES (1, '101.zip', 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 'Listado genérico del registro de entrada', myBlobVar);
END;
/

--informe 102
DECLARE
    myBlobVar BLOB := to_blob('xxxxxxx');
    dest_lob BLOB;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO SCR_REPORTS (ID, REPORT, TYPE_REPORT, TYPE_ARCH, ALL_ARCH, ALL_OFICS, ALL_PERFS, DESCRIPTION, "DATA")
        VALUES (2, '102.zip', 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 'Relación diaria por origen del registro de entrada', myBlobVar);
END;
/
```

Me da error al ejecutar las sentencias del script y me muestra este error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ORA-06550: l�a 5, columna 100:
PLS-00103: Se ha encontrado el s�olo "/"
```

Probé a quitar las "/", a introducir «COMMIT», inicializar la variable «myBlobVar» dentro de BEGIN... pero me sigue dando problemas. 
He de decir que si ejecuto las sentencias directamente en el SQL Developer me va bien, el problema está cuando las ejecuto con Maven.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ORA-06550: l�a 5, columna 101:
PLS-00103: Se ha encontrado el s�olo "/" 


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: ORA-06550: l�a 5, columna 101:
PLS-00103: Se ha encontrado el s�olo "/" 

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: ORA-06550: l�a 5, columna 101:
PLS-00103: Se ha encontrado el s�olo "/" 

    at org.codehaus.mojo.sql.SqlExecMojo.execute(SqlExecMojo.java:646)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: l�a 5, columna 101:
PLS-00103: Se ha encontrado el s�olo "/" 

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:754)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:210)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:963)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1192)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1731)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1701)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sql.SqlExecMojo.execSQL(SqlExecMojo.java:1011)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sql.SqlExecMojo.runStatements(SqlExecMojo.java:983)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sql.SqlExecMojo.access$200(SqlExecMojo.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sql.SqlExecMojo$Transaction.runTransaction(SqlExecMojo.java:1207)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sql.SqlExecMojo$Transaction.access$100(SqlExecMojo.java:1154)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sql.SqlExecMojo.execute(SqlExecMojo.java:612)
    ... 19 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10 minutes 43 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jan 14 09:21:16 CET 2020
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/562M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Actualización:**
Parece que sustituyendo "/" por ";" funciona correctamente al cargar desde Maven pero ahora si cargo el script desde SQL Developer no me funciona. ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar procedimientos en un mismo fichero sql en oracle?

Answer (score 1):

Quita el ; al final de cada `END` y solo dejas el /

Resulta que en Oracle se usa tanto el ; como / para hacer separación de scripts, si pones ambos en un mismo archivo para separar cada script, se ejecutará doblemente ocasionando problemas, por lo tanto es un estandar separar cada script del archivo con /